# Arduino Tweeting Weather Station

Tags: arduino

I want to create an Arduino Weather Station with
Temperature
Rain Gauge
Wind Speed
Wind Direction
Humidity

What peripherals should I be looking at getting?

Ideally I want this project to tweet the results - how do I do this?

Comment: How are you going to power this?  If it's off of batteries, how long would you want it to last?

Comment: This is awfully broad - it sounds like you're asking for a whole design. What have you done so far? What is stopping you at this point? Clearly you'll need a sensor for each of the measurements you want to make. Then you need a way to communicate the data. What have you planned so far?

Answer (score 4):

Sparkfun has a pretty comprehensive weather meter package that sounds like what you want listed as a [SEN-08942 Weather Meter](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/8942). For tweeting it depends on where it is, if you have WiFi available you can get a WiFi shield or if Ethernet is available an Ethernet shield. If neither of those are available you can use a cell phone data connection.

Answer (score 3):

Get yourself an Arduino board + ethernet shield. You'll need sensors (temperature, wind, humidity,...) aswell. You'll find a huge selection in your preffered online tech store. Then, learn some low level programming on Arduino, involving the ethernet library, code a small webclient and off you go. It's not rocket science ;)